# Accessing Javascript private variables with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

```
function Foo1() {
    var bar = 'test';
}
```

AFAIK, it is impossible to access the variable bar from global scope, unless one writes a privileged function to do so, such as

```
function Foo2() {
    var bar = 'test';
    this.read = function(){return bar;};
}
```

Does Greasemonkey (or any other tool) provide any means to access the variable bar, short of re-defining the entire function Foo1 with Foo2? 
Greasemonkey has GM_xmlhttprequest which sidesteps certain restrictions, so I was wondering if it could do this too and save me some issues.

What I am trying to do currently is to read and write a private variable embedded in a function, which is also itself located in a separate .js include. Thus, I cannot directly modify the script, and I have to load the .js with AJAX, carry out the modification, and then overwrite the original script. This is very cumbersome and I would like an easier way to carry this task out.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with Greasemonkey. You would need to use a Firebug-like tool (or API) which can inspect (and change) internal of the Javascript engine.

Comment: Since GM could run scripts under its own context, I was wondering whether it could do something similar and run under a private context, it would help greatly for debugging JS that was coded as private on certain sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GM_xmlhttprequest just bypasses browser security. Variable scope, on the other hand, is part of the language and the Javascript VM. Short of modifying the Javascript VM, there is no way to access those 'private' variables outside the function scope.

Answer (score -1):

If `Foo1` is not a native function and you do know the pattern of the function, then you can get the content of the variable by using:

```
var bar = /bar = '(\w+)'/.test(Foo1.toString()) && RegExp.$1;
alert(bar); // will return "test"
```

Comment: This would only work with static, string-based variables, and you still cannot use this to write the variable without completely recreating the function. Interesting hack, though.

Comment: The example should work without static, string-based variables too. I just followed your example. Basically you can't do what you want without this hack. Give a full practical example and I might give you another example.

Comment: function Foo1() {
    var bar = Math.random();
}                                                                                  Will the value still be able to read using this hack? I want the current value of random(), not the script itself.

Comment: This fool example is even easier... alert(Math.random()) should return the value you are looking for. :P
As I said, give a practical example.

Comment: I want the CURRENT value, which is pre-determined, and I do not want a second random number, which will be completely different from the first. If you have any idea which can return the value of bar that is CURRENTLY inside the function, please post that, otherwise it is of no help.

Comment: Sorry, can't help without a real example.

Comment: I guessed as much, if anyone who happens to chance upon this question manages to figure out what w35l3y is thinking, please do try to help resolve this problem by telling him what I actually mean. Thanks.

Comment: What do I need to say to make you understand that it is not possible without any hack and that a real example would help me to give you an example of hack that probably will work ?

Comment: Your examples are just fools and doesn't help anyone to help you. What is the point of having a random value in a local variable without any return statement ? Maybe you are doing something wrong and we could guide you to the right way. What is the problem of giving a real example ? Unless you are trying to do something illegal or unethical, then probably you won't get your answer here.